¿Cómo controlar la fecha en MongoDB con ZonedDateTime?
En una entidad, estoy usando la fecha de transacción para poder calcular una fecha de vencimiento sumando los días de plazo. Y como MongoDB no puede persistir por sí mismo campos ZonedDateTime, tengo la siguiente implementación para su lectura y escritura a nivel de base de datos.
Este es para persistir el campo en la base de datos.
@Component
public class ZonedDateTimeMongoDbWriter implements Converter<ZonedDateTime, Date> {

  @Override
  public Date convert(ZonedDateTime source) {
    return Date.from(source.toInstant());
  }

}

Y este es para extraer el campo de la base de datos:
@Component
public class ZonedDateTimeMongoDbReader implements Converter<Date, ZonedDateTime> {

  @Override
  public ZonedDateTime convert(Date source) {
    return source.toInstant()
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
  }

}

Lo que he notado es que, al estar en zona horaria de Lima (Perú), el día siguiente lo está considerando a partir de las 7pm y me puede crear inconsistencias para los reportes de consulta que pueda generar sobre la data que tiene campos de fecha. Entonces, revisando, me percato que se pierde la zona horaria al persistir los valores de fecha. ¿Cómo puedo resolver ese problema en base de datos? Sobre todo, al momento de truncar las fechas en días.

MongoDB almacena las fechas en horario UTC. No debes intentar modificar las fechas para que se almacenen en otra zona horaria. Lo suyo es implementar correctamente tu programa para que trabaje con UTC, esto te dará la consistencia de cálculo deseado ya sea que te encuentres en Lima, Prú o en Taiwan, tu programa podrá trabajar usando los mismos datos, adaptados a la zona horaria del cliente. Esto ya lo respondí antes.

Esta pregunta es similar a: como configuro mongoose para que me guarde en zona horaria -5:00?. Si crees que es diferente, por favor [edit] la pregunta, aclara en qué es diferente y/o cómo las respuestas en la otra pregunta no son útiles para tu problema.
